# how to access a list of objects array as a result of a JPQL's query

Tags: java, generics, jpa, collections, jpql

**Schema**: each Employee may have many phone numbers and each phone number belongs to an Employee (a one-to-Many Relationship).

Using the following JPQL query: `SELECT e, p FROM Employee e JOIN e.phones p`,

How would you handle the resulting `List<Object[]>` from this query in your application code? In terms of accessing each employee and his/her phone number in the app. Code from that `List<Object[]>`? Using

```
em.createNamedQuery("..").getResultList().get(1)[]
// or
em.createNamedQuery("..").getResultList().get(2)[0]
```

results in error.

Comment: You misspelled `createNamedQuery` and `getResulList` in the code above. Does your actual code even compile?

Comment: `results in error` - you might want to elaborate on the _exact_ error you get.

Comment: Hi Matt , sorry about the spelling.. didnt see it!!

Comment: hi Thomas the result is: "Cannot cast from List<Object> to List<Object[]>" getResultList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is that `getResultList()` returns a non generic `List` and thus you'd have to cast it to `List<Object[]>` first.

Assuming, your list has at least one entry this should work:

```
Employee e = (Employee)((List<Object[]>)em.createNamedQuery("..").getResultList()).get(0)[0];
```

*Update*:

Just for the reference: depending on the JPA version you use, you might get a `List<Object>` instead. In that case you could cast the value to `Object[]`:

```
Employee e = (Employee)((Object[])em.createNamedQuery("..").getResultList().get(0))[0];
```

Comment: thank for your help the problem lied in my app. code and i found it.